# Is it possible to compare variables in TypoScript?

Tags: typoscript

Is it possible to compare variables in TypoScript? If it is possible - then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I struggled with the very same issue, so here is what I found out. I was trying to include a plugin, but only if a certain TypoScript configuration variable was already set, which isn't possible using TypoScript conditions, because these don't have access to TypoScript variables!

So the way to go really is the ominous [`if`-function](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.5.0/view/1/5/#id2621713). The documentation says the following:

> This function returns true if ALL of the present conditions are met (they are AND'ed). If a single condition is false, the value returned is false.

What they do **not** mention is, that, if the `if`-function returns `false`, the Element in question is just not displayed/executed or whatever TypoScript actually does, for example:

```
10 = TEXT
10.value = foobar
10.if.value = 42
10.if.equals = 24
```

This TEXT-element would never be displayed, because the condition does not evaluate to true. The following however, would be displayed:

```
10 = TEXT
10.value = foobar
10.if.value = 42
10.if.isGreaterThan = 24
```

`if.value` always holds the value you are comparing to, and then there are a bunch of property you may use to compare another value to it.

The only good example in the documentation is this one:

> This is a GIFBUILDER object that will write "NEW" on a menu-item if the field "newUntil" has a date less than the current date!

```
...
30 = TEXT
30.text = NEW!
30.offset = 10,10
30.if {
    value.data = date: U
    isLessThan.field = newUntil
    negate = 1
}
...
```

---

**But beware... these properties are not available on any element type (`USER_INT` for example, does not have them)**.

What I did to workaround that problem was to wrap the `USER_INT` in a `COA` as follows:

```
config.enableMyStuff = 1
page.20 = COA
page.20 {
    10 =< plugin.tx_myextension_pi1
    if.value < config.enableMyStuff
    if.equals = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare variables by using the equals-keyword. If you typoscript is

```
10.value = 10
```

then you can assign a

```
10.equals = 10
```

and a condition

```
10.iftrue = 20
```

I'm sorry it's from my memory but you can read it in the typoscript manual. I want to say it's a recursive data structure using an adjacent tree model. Here is a link: http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.5.0/view/1/5/#id2621713

Comment: Sorry, i found nothing about a eq-keyword in the reference

Comment: here: http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.5.0/view/1/5/#id2621713

Comment: I do not really understand, what to do with the boolean, which i get after comparison of variables in typo... How can I change something, depending on the result, which if function returns. 
Assumed i have the following code:
<code>    MIDCONTENT = CONTENT
<code> MIDCONTENT{
<code>      table = tt_content
      select.orderBy = sorting
      select.where = colPos = 0  
   
   stdWrap.if{
     value=10
  isGreaterThan=5
   }
 }

Comment: Sorry, to be arrogant but the condition is true for the entire expression. So in your example it would return 5 if the value is greater then 10 AND the entire expression is true (AND typo3 will continue to use this Object).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with a normal [TypoScript "globalString" condition](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#globalstring) and a constant:

```
[globalString = LIT:foobar = {$some.typoscript.constant}]
    ...
[global]
```